# Is there Firefox add-on or Chrome extension that automatically creates a Google calendar from Gmail?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, gmail, google-calendar

Now that Google's own "Add to Calendar" function has disappeared from Gmail, is there Firefox add-on or Chrome extension that automatically creates a Google calendar from Gmail?  Email is the most frequent source of notifications for new events, so it would save many people a lot of time if translating a Gmail message into a Google Calendar event.

Comment: See the solution at [firefox - Automatically open ICS files in Google Calendar - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/44191/automatically-open-ics-files-in-google-calendar)

Answer (score 1):

[image] shows that the ability is still there in gmail.  Without plugins.  Are you sure it hasn't just moved from where you expect to see it?

When I send an e-mail with the title of **How would you like to catch lunch?** and include a mail body that looks like this:

> Would you like to go to lunch tomorrow around 2:00pm?

And then I receive a message and click on the "Create event" option on the "More" pull down, I get this in Google Calendar.

[image]

Bearing in mind that the time zones are differing by one hour between the two accounts.  The sender timezone was considered, and adjusted for the receiver.

Comment: Strange. The option was unavailable a few hours ago when I tried, but I see it now.

Nonetheless, the Create event within Gmail leaves a lot to be desired. It doesn't seem to pick up the time from the email; it creates all the other recipients of the email in the guest list, which is unnecessary.

I wish there was a plug-in or add-on that's smart enough to pick up the day, time and place. Is there?

Comment: What is missing from the functionality?  It might be necessary, you can remove them.  If they are in the e-mail it might be assumed that they were in the discussion.  Only sending a test message to my account, it works as I expect.  Title says: How would you like to catch lunch?  The body says: Would you like to go to lunch tomorrow around 2:00pm?  And I create event as shown in the picture, and I get this: Tomorrow's date, and the time in my time zone as compared to the other account (So it even automatically adjusted the time.) See my edited answer above for what I get.

Comment: The result must depend on the content of the email, because when I tried "create event" on another email, it also failed. The function wouldn't recognize the date and time in the email, and insert today's date and current time in the calendar.

Comment: Yes, it for sure does depend on the content of the mail body.  Some examples of failure would probably be good to see.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you: http://boomerangcalendar.com/

It still doesn't have everything, but it's better than the simple create event feature built into gmail.